# In python pandas DataFrames, what are the rules for automatic type conversion when setting values?

Tags: python, pandas, casting

If I have a dataframe which looks like

```
import pandas

d = pandas.DataFrame( data = {'col1':[100,101,102,103] } )
#   col1
#0   100
#1   101
#2   102
#3   103
```

and I do

```
d.set_value( 0,'col1', '200')
```

it casts '200' to an integer:

```
type( d.col1[0] )
#numpy.int64
```

however if I do

```
d.set_value( 0,'col2', '200')
```

I get

```
type( d.col2[0] )
#str
```

as expected.

### More mysteries:

Further, say I do the following

```
[ type(x) for x in d.col1 ]
#[numpy.int64, numpy.int64, numpy.int64, numpy.int64]
d.set_value( [0,1,2,3], 'col1', ['101', '102', '103', 200] )
[ type(x) for x in d.col1 ]
#[str, str, str, str]
```

So even though `d.col1` was originally an integer column, it has now become a string column. What are the rules for such type casting of entire columns ?

I am just curious what the rules are for automatic type-casting when manipulating pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

pandas is column-major and every element in the same column must have the same data type.

When you create a dataframe using

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[100,101,102,103]})
df.col.dtype

Out[11]:
dtype('int64')
```

pandas automatically infer that all these input are numeric values and of integer type. So when you set values for this column `col`, all your inputs will be automatically casted into the current column `dtype` which is `int64`, so the following will give you exactly the same output

```
df.set_value(0, 'col', '200')  # cast string into int
df.set_value(0, 'col', 200)  # int input
df.set_value(0, 'col', 200.1)  # cast float64 into int64
```

But when you try to do `df.set_value(0, 'col1', '200')`, the current `df` has no column `col1`, so pandas first create a new column named `col1`, and it will try to infer the dtype for this new column based on your input.

```
df.set_value(0, 'col1', '200')
df.col1.dtype  # dtype('O'), means object/string
df.set_value(0, 'col2', 200.1)
df.col2.dtype  # dtype('float64')
```

Comment: thats for some explanation, but there seems to be a bit more to the story, see what I'm about to add above